# Putting different elements into one column from xml in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012, xquery

I have the following part of an XML document:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
    <IPCScheme xmlns="http://depatisnet.dpma.de/ipc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://depatisnet.dpma.de/ipc ipc_scheme_3-1_dpma.xsd" edition="20190101" lang="EN">
       <ipcEntry  symbol="A01D0000000000" kind="u" entryType="K">
           <textBody><title>
               <titlePart>
                   <text> HARVESTING </text>
               </titlePart>
               <titlePart>
                   <text> MOWING</text>
               </titlePart>
           </title></textBody>
       </ipcEntry>
       <ipcEntry  symbol="A01F0000000000" kind="u" entryType="K">
           <textBody><title>
               <titlePart>
                   <text> THRESHING</text>
                   <entryReference> combines 
                       <sref ref="A01D0041000000"></sref>
                   </entryReference>
               </titlePart>
               <titlePart>
                   <text> BALING OF STRAW, HAY OR THE LIKE</text>
               </titlePart>
               <titlePart>
                   <text> STATIONARY APPARATUS OR HAND TOOLS FOR FORMING OR BINDING STRAW, HAY OR THE LIKE INTO BUNDLES</text>
               </titlePart>
               <titlePart>
                   <text> CUTTING OF STRAW, HAY OR THE LIKE</text>
               </titlePart>
               <titlePart>
                   <text> STORING AGRICULTURAL OR HORTICULTURAL PRODUCE</text>
                   <entryReference> arrangements for making or setting stacks in connection with harvesting 
                       <sref ref="A01D0085000000"></sref>
                   </entryReference>
               </titlePart>
           </title></textBody>
       </ipcEntry>
       <ipcEntry symbol="A01B0000000000" kind="u" entryType="K">
           <textBody><title>
               <titlePart>
                    <text> SOIL WORKING IN AGRICULTURE OR FORESTRY</text>
               </titlePart>
               <titlePart>
                   <text> PARTS, DETAILS, OR ACCESSORIES OF AGRICULTURAL MACHINES OR IMPLEMENTS, IN GENERAL</text>
                   <entryReference> making or covering furrows or holes for sowing, planting or manuring 
                       <sref ref="A01C0005000000"></sref>
                   </entryReference>
                   <entryReference> machines for harvesting root crops 
                       <sref ref="A01D0000000000"></sref>
                   </entryReference>
                   <entryReference> mowers convertible to soil working apparatus or capable of soil working
                       <sref ref="A01D0042040000"></sref>
                   </entryReference>
                   <entryReference> mowers combined with soil working implements 
                       <sref ref="A01D0043120000"></sref>
                   </entryReference>
                   <entryReference>soil working for engineering purposes 
                       <sref ref="E01"></sref> , 
                       <sref ref="E02"></sref> , 
                       <sref ref="E21"></sref>
                   </entryReference>
               </titlePart>
           </title></textBody>
       </ipcEntry>
 </IPCScheme>
```

The goal is to have a column with the symbol and a column with concatenate text including the information for each ipc Entry.

```
Symbol          String
A01B0000000000  SOIL WORKING IN AGRICULTURE OR FORESTRY; PARTS, DETAILS, OR ACCESSORIES OF AGRICULTURAL MACHINES OR IMPLEMENTS, IN GENERAL (making or covering furrows or holes for sowing, planting or manuring A01C 5/00; machines for harvesting root crops A01D; mowers convertible to soil working apparatus or capable of soil working A01D 42/04; mowers combined with soil working implements A01D 43/12; soil working for engineering purposes E01, E02, E21)
A01D0000000000  HARVESTING; MOWING
A01F0000000000  THRESHING (combines A01D 41/00); BALING OF STRAW, HAY OR THE LIKE; STATIONARY APPARATUS OR HAND TOOLS FOR FORMING OR BINDING STRAW, HAY OR THE LIKE INTO BUNDLES; CUTTING OF STRAW, HAY OR THE LIKE; STORING AGRICULTURAL OR HORTICULTURAL PRODUCE (arrangements for making or setting stacks in connection with harvesting A01D 85/00)
```

I already made a query which excludes the last separator and which only includes the brackets when an entry References is made so there is no "()" for symbols where we don´t have an entry References. But to keep it simple because the issue is to include the queries in itself I left this part in the following query.

```
    DECLARE @xml  XML
    Select @xml =P
    FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\Users\File.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS Products(P)
    ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://depatisnet.dpma.de/ipc',
                            'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as xsi)
    SELECT
        MY_XML.IPC.value('@symbol', 'NVARCHAR(max)') as Symbol,
        concat(left(MY_XML.IPC.query('for $i in textBody/title/titlePart/text return concat($i, ";")').value('.','NVARCHAR(max)'), len(MY_XML.IPC.query('for $i in textBody/title/titlePart/text return concat($i, ";")').value('.','NVARCHAR(max)'))-1),' (',My_XML.IPC.query('for $i in textBody/title/titlePart/entryReference return concat($i, ($i/sref/@ref)[1] , ";")').value('.','NVARCHAR(max)'),')') as String
    FROM @xml.nodes('IPCScheme/ipcEntry/ipcEntry/ipcEntry') MY_XML(IPC)
```

This was the result:

```
    Symbol         String
    A01B0000000000 SOIL WORKING IN AGRICULTURE OR FORESTRY; PARTS, DETAILS, OR ACCESSORIES OF AGRICULTURAL MACHINES OR IMPLEMENTS, IN GENERAL (making or covering furrows or holes for sowing, planting or manuring A01C0005000000; ; machines for harvesting root crops A01D0000000000; mowers convertible to soil working apparatus or capable of soil working A01D0042040000; mowers combined with soil working implements A01D0043120000; soil working for engineering purposes  ,  , E01;)
    A01D0000000000 HARVESTING; MOWING ()
    A01F0000000000 THRESHING;  BALING OF STRAW, HAY OR THE LIKE; STATIONARY APPARATUS OR HAND TOOLS FOR FORMING OR BINDING STRAW, HAY OR THE LIKE INTO BUNDLES; CUTTING OF STRAW, HAY OR THE LIKE; STORING AGRICULTURAL OR HORTICULTURAL PRODUCE (combines A01D0041000000; arrangements for making or setting stacks in connection with harvesting A01D0085000000;)
```

So all entryReferences are by construction added to the end of the text which is correct when entryReferences are added at the last titlePart but not in general and additionally I only get to include one sref/@ref. What I need is some kind of query which query for every titlepart the different elements and add it to the full string in a way I want it to.

edited:
All in all i want for every ipcEntry the attribute symbol and for every ipcEntry one combined text which has for every titlePart the element text followed by "(" and the entryReference and the attribute @ref from sref followed by ");" and the next titlePart. All elements can have more than one text, entryReference or sref which makes this somehow challenging. The first table after the xml fragment is what i want. The second table after the sql-code is what i get.

Hopefully you can give some thoughts on this. Thanks in advance

**Solution by @Shnugo slightly edited**

```
 ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://depatisnet.dpma.de/ipc')
 SELECT entr.value('@symbol','nvarchar(100)') AS Symbol
       ,STUFF(
        (
        SELECT CONCAT('; ',B.tp.value('(text/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)'))
              ,CASE WHEN B.tp.exist('entryReference')=1 THEN
               CONCAT(' ('
                      ,STUFF(
                       (
                        SELECT CONCAT('; ',C.er.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(100)'))
                            ,CASE WHEN C.er.exist('sref')=1 THEN
                            STUFF(
                                (
                                 Select Concat(', ', D.ad.value('@ref[1]','nvarchar(100)'))
                                 From C.er.nodes('sref') D(ad)
                                 For XML PATH('')
                                 ),1,2,'') End
                        FROM B.tp.nodes('entryReference') C(er)
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                       ),1,2,'')
                      ,')') END
        FROM A.entr.nodes('textBody/title/titlePart') B(tp)
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1,1,'') AS ConcatenatedTextNodes 
 FROM @xml.nodes('/IPCScheme/ipcEntry') A(entr);
```

Comment: Can you post valid xml? I copied your sample into an xml file on my machine and ran your code. "Msg 9410, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
XML parsing: line 38, character 50, whitespace expected"

Comment: @SeanLange the line: `<ipcEntry symbol="A01B0000000000" kind="u"entryType="K">`... put a space between "u" and "entryType="K"... e.g. space after the "u" in this example ^^^

Comment: Your question is worded in a very confusing manner. Can you provide the result you expect from this XML fragment?

Comment: @AlanBurstein you are right. I edited the xml fragment, now it should work. Sorry for not testing it again.

Comment: @RogerWolf it´s my first one so yes, definitely a long road ahead. I want the result in the table after the xml fragment. With my posted code i only get the table after the sql code. I need to query through the text and entryReference elements and the sref attributes at the same time but i can only query through them seperatly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many approaches to solve this:

Assuming your XML is read into a xml typed variable (Hint: get rid of the `<??>` declaration):

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<IPCScheme xmlns="http://depatisnet.dpma.de/ipc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://depatisnet.dpma.de/ipc ipc_scheme_3-1_dpma.xsd" edition="20190101" lang="EN">
       <ipcEntry  symbol="A01D0000000000" kind="u" entryType="K">
           <textBody><title>
               <titlePart>
                   <text> HARVESTING </text>
               </titlePart>
               <titlePart>
                   <text> MOWING</text>
               </titlePart>
           </title></textBody>
       </ipcEntry>
       <ipcEntry  symbol="A01F0000000000" kind="u" entryType="K">
           <textBody><title>
               <titlePart>
                   <text> THRESHING</text>
                   <entryReference> combines 
                       <sref ref="A01D0041000000"></sref>
                   </entryReference>
               </titlePart>
               <titlePart>
                   <text> BALING OF STRAW, HAY OR THE LIKE</text>
               </titlePart>
               <titlePart>
                   <text> STATIONARY APPARATUS OR HAND TOOLS FOR FORMING OR BINDING STRAW, HAY OR THE LIKE INTO BUNDLES</text>
               </titlePart>
               <titlePart>
                   <text> CUTTING OF STRAW, HAY OR THE LIKE</text>
               </titlePart>
               <titlePart>
                   <text> STORING AGRICULTURAL OR HORTICULTURAL PRODUCE</text>
                   <entryReference> arrangements for making or setting stacks in connection with harvesting 
                       <sref ref="A01D0085000000"></sref>
                   </entryReference>
               </titlePart>
           </title></textBody>
       </ipcEntry>
       <ipcEntry symbol="A01B0000000000" kind="u" entryType="K">
           <textBody><title>
               <titlePart>
                    <text> SOIL WORKING IN AGRICULTURE OR FORESTRY</text>
               </titlePart>
               <titlePart>
                   <text> PARTS, DETAILS, OR ACCESSORIES OF AGRICULTURAL MACHINES OR IMPLEMENTS, IN GENERAL</text>
                   <entryReference> making or covering furrows or holes for sowing, planting or manuring 
                       <sref ref="A01C0005000000"></sref>
                   </entryReference>
                   <entryReference> machines for harvesting root crops 
                       <sref ref="A01D0000000000"></sref>
                   </entryReference>
                   <entryReference> mowers convertible to soil working apparatus or capable of soil working
                       <sref ref="A01D0042040000"></sref>
                   </entryReference>
                   <entryReference> mowers combined with soil working implements 
                       <sref ref="A01D0043120000"></sref>
                   </entryReference>
                   <entryReference>soil working for engineering purposes 
                       <sref ref="E01"></sref> , 
                       <sref ref="E02"></sref> , 
                       <sref ref="E21"></sref>
                   </entryReference>
               </titlePart>
           </title></textBody>
       </ipcEntry>
 </IPCScheme>';
```

--The easiest approach is XQuery's `data()`. But this will use a blank as separator in any case. It's a pitty, that we cannot set a separator as parameter.

```
 WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://depatisnet.dpma.de/ipc')
 SELECT entr.value('@symbol','nvarchar(100)') AS Symbol
       ,entr.query('data(.//text)').value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS ConcatenatedTextNodes
 FROM @xml.nodes('/IPCScheme/ipcEntry') A(entr);
```

--This will use a nested `FOR XML PATH('')` to simulate a grouped concatenation and `STUFF()` to cut away the leading `;`
--Advantage: Her I can use `TRIM()` (`LTRIM()` and `RTRIM()` in older versions) easily.

```
 WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://depatisnet.dpma.de/ipc')
 SELECT entr.value('@symbol','nvarchar(100)') AS Symbol
       ,STUFF(
        (
        SELECT CONCAT('; ',TRIM(t.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(100)')))
        FROM entr.nodes('./textBody/title/titlePart/text') B(t)
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1,1,'') AS ConcatenatedTextNodes 
 FROM @xml.nodes('/IPCScheme/ipcEntry') A(entr);
```

--This is roughly the same as above, but uses XQuery's FLWOR approach:

```
 WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://depatisnet.dpma.de/ipc')
 SELECT entr.value('@symbol','nvarchar(100)') AS Symbol
       ,STUFF(
        entr.query('for $t in ./textBody/title/titlePart/text/text()
                    return <t>{concat(";",$t)}</t>')
            .value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'') AS ConcatenatedTextNodes
 FROM @xml.nodes('/IPCScheme/ipcEntry') A(entr);
```

--And finally, if you are lucky using v2017 already, you can use `STRING_AGG()`

```
 WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://depatisnet.dpma.de/ipc')
 ,cte AS
 (
     SELECT entr.value('@symbol','nvarchar(100)') AS Symbol
           ,t.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS TextNode
     FROM @xml.nodes('/IPCScheme/ipcEntry') A(entr)
     CROSS APPLY A.entr.nodes('./textBody/title/titlePart/text') B(t)
 )
 SELECT Symbol
       ,STRING_AGG(TextNode,';')
 FROM cte
 GROUP BY Symbol;
```

### UPDATE Sorry, I should've read your own attempt more carefully...

You can try something along this to get the combined values:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://depatisnet.dpma.de/ipc')
 SELECT entr.value('@symbol','nvarchar(100)') AS Symbol
       ,STUFF(
        (
        SELECT CONCAT('; ',TRIM(B.tp.value('(text/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)')))
              ,CASE WHEN B.tp.exist('entryReference')=1 THEN
               CONCAT(' ('
                      ,STUFF(
                       (
                        SELECT CONCAT('; ',TRIM(C.er.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(100)')))
                        FROM B.tp.nodes('entryReference') C(er)
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                       ),1,2,'')
                      ,')') END
        FROM A.entr.nodes('textBody/title/titlePart') B(tp)
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1,1,'') AS ConcatenatedTextNodes 
 FROM @xml.nodes('/IPCScheme/ipcEntry') A(entr);
```

Regrettfully within XQuery FLWOR we do not have `normalize-space()` or `trim()`, so the embedded blanks would blow this up.

The solution above uses a `CASE WHEN` to add the `()` only to titleParts, where there is at least one `<entryReference>`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am using the version of 2012. I not only need the text elements but i also need the entryReference elements with sref/@ref in brackets like in the first table after the xml fragment.

Comment: That is a perfect fit. I also needed the attributes in the sref element but i just added another level to your updated code. I think i can´t use the trim function in my version but this is no problem at all. It does not look very intuitive in the first place but i think i will get a handle on it. I added my full code to the question. Thanks a lot!